# How to merge transparent PNG Image with color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I tried with `drawInRect` and `CGContextDrawImage` but it is applying to the whole image.

I want it to apply to the image part only, not to the transparent part. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If someone to put some effort into answering your question, you might want to put some effort into writing your question.... 1) Show your code 2) What did you expect? 3) What did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help...i tried this code it worked for me finally.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImage.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, firstImage.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, firstImage.size.width, firstImage.size.height);
// draw black background to preserve color of transparent pixels
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
// draw original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, firstImage.CGImage);
// tint image (loosing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDarken);
[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:secondImage] setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
// mask by alpha values of original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, firstImage.CGImage);
//[firstImage drawInRect:rect];

// image drawing code here
UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use `UIImage` with alpha channel as mask for drawing.

#### Objective-C

```
- (UIImage *)overlayImage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    //  Create rect to fit the PNG image
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    //  Start drawing
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //  Fill the rect by the final color
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    //  Make the final shape by masking the drawn color with the images alpha values
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
    [image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1];

    //  Create new image from the context
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //  Release context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Example usage:

```
UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
UIColor *overlayColor = [UIColor magentaColor];

UIImage *image = [self overlayImage:pngImage withColor:overlayColor];
```

#### Swift 3

```
extension UIImage {

    func overlayed(by overlayColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        //  Create rect to fit the image
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        // Create image context. 0 means scale of device's main screen
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        //  Fill the rect by the final color
        overlayColor.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        //  Make the final shape by masking the drawn color with the images alpha values
        self.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .destinationIn, alpha: 1)

        //  Create new image from the context
        let overlayedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

        //  Release context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return overlayedImage
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let overlayedImage = myImage.overlayed(by: .magenta)
```

---

**Edit**: as Desdenova pointed out in the comment, I misunderstood the question. My original answer was drawing the PNG over a colored background. Answer edited, code below is the original one.

```
- (UIImage *)combineImage:(UIImage *)image withBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)bgColor
{
    //  Create rect to fit the PNG image
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    //  Create bitmap contect
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Draw background first

    //  Set background color (will be under the PNG)
    [bgColor setFill];

    //  Fill all context with background image
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    //  Draw the PNG over the background
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    //  Create new image from the context
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //  Release context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: **`Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime`**

Comment: I think what he needs is the other way around. Keep the transparency and paint the rest.

Comment: @Bala "Give a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day; set fire to the man, and he'll be warm for a lifetime."

Comment: @Desdenova you were right, I misunderstood the question. Answer fixed, thanks

Comment: @Maarten i want to warm you now for lifetime ;)

Comment: Why are you doing `CGContextSaveGState` if there is no `CGContextRestoreGState` later? Seems pointless and maybe leaks

Comment: Quick addition to respect the retina scale: Replace "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext" with "UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);"

Answer (score 0):

I've applied the code below on a button click to fill my transparent PNG with color.

```
UIImage *colouredImage = _oldImageView.image;
colouredImage = [colouredImage imageTintedWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:99/255.0 green:4/255.0 blue:96/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
_oldImageView.image = colouredImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too and I think @Lukas Kukacka answer is a great solution. 
I would like to add a bit more to this solution and I recommend to use a Category for it.
Why category? Because in my case, I am using this "method" in multiple classes so instead of writing the same code multiple times I will do just once.

Let´s see the code:
This will be the UIImage+OverlayTintColor.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (OverlayTintColor)
- (UIImage *)overlayTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

@end
```

This will be the UIImage+OverlayTintColor.m

```
#import "UIImage+OverlayTintColor.h"

@implementation UIImage (OverlayTintColor)

- (UIImage *)overlayTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor{

        //  Create rect to fit the PNG image
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);

        //  Start drawing
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        //  Fill the rect by the final color
        [tintColor setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        //  Make the final shape by masking the drawn color with the images alpha values
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
        [self drawInRect: rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1];

        //  Create new image from the context
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        //  Release context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
}

@end
```

Usage:(Dont forget to import the category at the top of the class where you are going to use it)

```
#import "UIImage+OverlayTintColor.h"


.......



 UIImage *image=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] overlayTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```